# How do I compile this on mac by terminal command

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, compilation

I am using xcode to compile my opencv project, and I have some settings as below:

```
    HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = /usr/local/include

    LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS = /usr/local/lib

    OTHER_LDFLAGS = -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_core -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_ml -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_photo -lopencv_shape -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_ts -lopencv_video -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_videostab
```

I want to know what shall I write by terminal command rather than setting of xcode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you installed `OpenCV` with `homebrew` and you also installed the `pkgconfig` package with `homebrew`, the package can tell you the settings you need itself - far more accurately than you can guess them.

The easy way is to ask `pkgconfig` to list all the packages it knows about:

```
pkg-config --list-all | grep -i opencv

opencv                 OpenCV - Open Source Computer Vision Library
```

So, now you know the package name is plain and simple `opencv`, and you can find the flags you need like this:

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv
-I/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.12_2/include/opencv \
-I/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.12_2/include \
-L/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.12_2/lib \
-lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_core -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_gpu -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_ml -lopencv_nonfree -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_ocl -lopencv_photo -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_ts -lopencv_video -lopencv_videostab
```

Which means your compilation and linking becomes simply:

```
g++ $(pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv) program.cpp -o program
```

If you do that in a Makefile, you will need to double up the `$` signs.

If your system is not so well installed, you may need to find the `pkgconfig` file yourself. So you would do:

```
find /usr/local -name "opencv*pc"
/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.12_2/lib/pkgconfig/opencv.pc
```

Then you can access that file specifically like this:

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.12_2/lib/pkgconfig/opencv.pc
```

Comment: Wow,your answer is quite useful to me,I haven't known pkgconfig ever.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
g++ -I ${HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS} -L ${LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS} ${OTHER_LDFLAGS} ${SOURCE_FILES}
```