# How can I print the paths of the headers and libraries of an installed Homebrew formula?

Tags: homebrew

Is there a way to print the header and lib include paths for a Homebrew formula (which usually briefly show up during installation)? Something like this:

```
$ brew paths opencv3
-I/path/to/opencv3/include
-L/path/to/opencv3/lib
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36999364/2836621

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to use pkgconfig:

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv
```

which outputs

```
-I/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.13.2/include/opencv -I/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.13.2/include -L/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.13.2/lib -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_core -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_gpu -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_ml -lopencv_nonfree -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_ocl -lopencv_photo -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_ts -lopencv_video -lopencv_videostab
```