# Can't build an OpenCV project in Xcode 6.4 for yosemite

Tags: xcode, opencv, opencv3.0

I am having a problem while trying to set up openCV with Xcode for the first time. I followed the instructions on these two videos [openCV setup](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U49CVY8yOxw) [openCV with Xcode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XJeP1juuHHY)

When I try to build the project at the end of video 2 I get the following build error :

```html
ld: library not found for -lopencv_imgcodecs
```

I followed the instructions step by step, I did this twice to confirm that I am not missing on any details.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36999364/2836621

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34341219/2836621